# Помогите с базой данных на nodemcu (esp8266)

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, arduino, esp8266

мне нужно хранить показаниая с датчиков тока в базе данных непосредственно на самом nodemcu. У этого модуля есть память 4 мб. В интернете видел библиотеку sqlite V3, но самому разобраться трудно. Может есть у кого опыт с базами данных?

Comment: А точно нужна база данных? Для простого хранения показаний датчиков база данных не требуется, достаточно обычного csv, например. Какая конкретно у  вас задача и на чем пишите код (c++/arduino, Lua, micropython)?

Answer (score 2):

Вам не нужна БД для хранения нескольких серий данных. Тем более на NodeMCU который при рестарте все позабудет (если не писать на энергонезависимую память). Достаточно просто сохранять в массиве и периодически сбрасывать, например, на SD карту в CSV. А дальше уже зависит от применения.